# Class Array having 2 arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, class

so basically I'd like to return an array class when returning another class.

I have this code, where it creates a player class, and it has an array field.

This piece of code is taken from [Classes - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

```
class MyArray extends Array {
// Overwrite species to the parent Array constructor
static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }
```

}

Like so:

```
class Player {
constructor() {
    this.CustomArray = new MyArray([1,2,3,4])
}
```

However, this returns 
`MyArray [[1,2,3,4]]`

It now has 2 arrays while I just want one.

I'd like it to be, `MyArray [1,2,3]`

How would I be able to do this?

Comment: What is the purpose of `MyArray` as opposed to just using an array?

Comment: Because when having the player class, I’d like to have my IDE to show what functions I can do with that array, and to tell it that it is an array.

Comment: There's no need at all for `MyArray`, then. Just `this.customArray = [1, 2, 3, 4];` Your IDE understands arrays. Of course, if you were going to *add* functions to `MyArray` that arrays don't have, that would be different. :-) (Side Note: I used a lowercase `c` in `customArray` because the *overwhelming* convention in JavaScript is that property names start with a lowercase letter; we basically only use an initial capital for constructor functions.)

Comment: Side note: Unless you want `var a = new MyArray(1, 2, 3, 4); var b = a.slice();` to make `b` an `Array`, not a `MyArray`, there's no need for the `Symbol.species` stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array constructor accepts *plain variables* to put into the array as elements of the array - it does not accept an array itself (unless you want to create an array of arrays as you did above). So, just remove the `[]` in your call of the constructor:

```js
class MyArray extends Array {
  // Overwrite species to the parent Array constructor
  static get [Symbol.species]() { return Array; }

}
class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.CustomArray = new MyArray(...someExistingArray)
  }
}
const p = new Player();
console.log(JSON.stringify(p.CustomArray));
```

Comment: Well, the array I’m going to set is not just 1,2,3,4 etc. it’s previous player names which will be an array. Would I have to unpack the array first or something like that ?

Comment: Yes, but that's easy: just use the spread operator, see edit. (your previous player names *should* have more than one element though, or you can run into problems)

Comment: `...` isn't an operator (in fact, it can't be, it doesn't have a single result value).

Answer (score 2):

`new MyArray([1, 2, 3, 4])` says "Create a new `MyArray` with a single entry, which is the array `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. If you want to create an array containing `1, 2, 3, 4`, remove the `[]`: `new MyArray(1, 2, 3, 4)`. (But beware: If you did `new MyArray(1)`, it would treat that number as the number of places the array should have, and create an empty array with `length` = 1. [Sad but true, the `Array` constructor special-cases if you pass it one argument and that argument is a number. You could override that in `MyArray` of course.])

If you have a source array and want to put all of the entries from it into your `customArray`, you have a couple of options:

1. As [CaptainPerformance notes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49829298/157247), you can use spread notation:

   ```
   this.customArray = new MyArray(...theOtherArray);
   ```
2. If you remove the probably-unnecessary `Symbol.species` property, you can use `MyArray.from`:

   ```
   this.customArray = MyArray.from(theOtherArray);
   ```

   (If you keep your species override, that will just produce a normal array.)
3. Use `Object.assign`:

   ```
   this.customArray = Object.assign(new MyArray(), theOtherArray);
   ```
4. Use `apply` with `push`:

   ```
   this.customArray = new MyArray();
   this.customArray.push.apply(this.customArray, theOtherArray);
   ```